# ISC DHCP Server - Deny known client with fixed-address from pool

Tags: dhcp

I have many known hosts with fixed ip address.

I'm trying to configure my DHCP server to not give ip address dynamically to them.

I know that it's possible with ACL but I can't add manually all the 1000 mac address.

Comment: please add more detail in this question

Answer (score 0):

> I have many known hosts with fixed ip address.

If your host already has a static IP address, there is no need for a DHCP server for them. It will not even try to retrieve an IP. So I'm not too sure what you are asking.

If you want a computer to get a specific (static) IP address via DHCP, the only way is to use their MAC address and enter a corresponding IP for that computer. With the ISC DHCP server this is done this way:

```
 host computer_name {
    hardware ethernet 11:22:33:44:55:66;
    fixed-address 10.0.1.2;
}
```

If you have so many computers, you can always write a script to generate those lines. You'll need to gather the 1,000 MAC address in some way, though. If you're already connected, those will be listed in the `/proc/net/arp` file along the existing IP addresses.

Yet again, if all of these 1,000 computers were already assigned an IP address, they do not require a DHCP client and thus no need for the bother in the first place.

With `netplan`, this would be something like this:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
                - 10.0.1.2/16
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            optional: false
            gateway4: 10.0.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: 
                    - 8.8.8.8
                    - 8.8.4.4
```

The main options are the `dhcp[46]` set to false which means no DHCP client will be used and thus whether you have a DHCP server somewhere is totally ignored by this computer.

On older computers, you'd use the old scheme which is the "network interfaces". (`/etc/network/interfaces` and possibly the sub-folder `/etc/network/interfaces.d/<interface-name>`).

The interface definition with the old ifconfig required more details like so:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.0.1.2
  netmask 255.255.0.0
  network 10.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.0.255.255
  gateway 10.0.0.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

In newer versions, the masks must be all ones then all zeroes. A mask such as 255.255.0.240 is not allowed anymore. This is why newer versions use the `.../<count>` syntax.